# Why does Frankenstein need multiple bodies to revive a body

Tags: frankensteins-monster

In *Mary Shelly's Frankenstein* (movie) at the end *Dr. Frankenstein* revives his wife. But why did he need to transplant her head onto another body? Wouldn't it be better to keep the body intact as much as possible?

Comment: I can think of a smart-ass answer to this, but I'm going to be mature and rise above it.

Comment: To make Helena Bonham Carter look as creepy as possible? :P

Comment: If I recall the movie correctly, it's because the original body's heart was too damaged. But I haven't seen it in some time.

Comment: @Roger: well the *"monster"* had removed the heart. But in that case, transplanting the heart would be more obvious. If Frankenstein can manage to transplant a head, a heart is easier...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certain organs in the original body were damaged so Victor Frankenstein had to pick and choose parts of different corpses for optimal functionality.